# Is there a way to have 2 Factor Authentication on a specific application running on windows?

Tags: windows, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to set up a 2FA system for a third party application. When a user clicks on this application's icon and it starts, it will ask for a PIN, which the user will have to input before being allowed to start the application. [I've attached a workflow chart to illustrate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul9RI.jpg)

I'm wondering if there's a way to to do this with any existing 2FA solutions (Authy/WinAuth etc.). If not, what is the best approach to creating an application like this?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it is not 2FA as it will only ask for one factor.
In general, if the app itself does not have it, then it will not be possible the way your workflow illustrates. What can be done is the following: you host the app on a different machine, and access to that machine is secured with 2FA (not only the PIN/OTP but also a username+password pair). Citrix XenApp or similar platform can do that.